# error when forming matrix, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to get a matrix `a` by `b`. However I get an error with the below code.
The errors occur on the line

```
NV(b,:)=(a;b);
```

errors are:

> invalid syntax at "," or missing ), ]
>   and parse error at ")"

This is the code:

```
n=2;
g1= 1:1:10;
g=10.^(g1/10); %SNR

for a= 0:g %diff SNR
for b= 1:n %DIFF USERS
    NV(b,:)=(a;b); % NOISE VAR, MATRIX FOR DIFF SNR AND DIFF USERS.
end
 end
```

What might cause these errors and how do I solve them?
thanks

Comment: Are you aware that you are looping to `g` which is a 10*1 vector, not a scalar? ps your code has several other problems, but this one probably needs to be resolved first.

Comment: what does (a;b) means? probably you ment (a,b)

Comment: hi guys, thanks for all the replies, after reading back over the theory i managed to solve it,. there was a bit of confusion and had to change a lot of the code. but thanks again for all the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NV is not defined before you try to access all elements of the second matrix dimension. That is essentially saying "set all of an unknown quantity"--it could be one or it could be infinity. It is not a well formed statement.

The rest of that line is a little odd too and not valid syntax since it looks like you're trying to create an array of arrays.

I'm not positive exactly what you're doing (how big is the second dimension of NV supposed to be and whether or not my correction of "NV(b,:)=[a;b];" is what you intended), but this syntax compiles/runs and hopefully gets you started in the right direction.

```
n=2;
g1= 1:1:10;
g=10.^(g1/10); %SNR

NV = zeros(n,n); % Create an empty n-by-n matrix
                 % Note: Defining the final matrix size outside of a loop
                 %       also improves performance

for a= 0:g %diff SNR
    for b= 1:n %DIFF USERS
        NV(b,:)=[a;b]; % NOISE VAR, MATRIX FOR DIFF SNR AND DIFF USERS.
    end
end
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, i was wondering if its possible to make a slight change. so as " g " gives 10 different values, how would you go about producing a matrix NV which has dimensions of  g by n,

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html for usage of the zeros function. The Mathworks documentation is very good and I would recommend doing some reading on that website to learn about some of the basic functions.